# Include email signature when sending an email though MS Graph API

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I have an enterprise UWP application in which I send emails using the Microsoft Graph API.

In these emails I would like to include the authenticated user's email signature.

I have tested using an Office365 account with the email signature set with no success. Having read the Graph API documentation I can find no way to either include or download a user's signature.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the current MS Graph API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email signatures aren’t stored in a mailbox. Email signatures are stored and set in each client. For example, you might want to have a different email signature on your phone as it may make sense to let the email recipient know that you are composing on a device that doesn't lend to composing long emails. The expectations may be different when sending from a more full featured client.

You'll want to implement signatures in your client. Append the signature to the end of the message body.

With that said, you could store an email signature somewhere and always use it from your application. For example, you could use [OneDrive](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive) to store an email signature text file.

Comment: Your answer aroused my curiosity on how OWA currently work with the email signature and reasons for this limitation compared to legacy way of doing the same. Could you please enlighten me?  Thanks.

Comment: @kushan, I'm sorry, I have no idea how OWA handles email signatures

Comment: @MichaelMainer you can access an OWA signature via UserConfiguration in EWS that is if it's been setup. I stumbled across this response when trying to research doing the smae via Graph due to the on coming retirement of EWS. Eventually signatures will be stored centrally but yet to be implemented by MS

Comment: Thank you @BenMorris for pointing that out. I see the pain for those of you moving from EWS to Microsoft Graph when encountering these cases where the MSGraph API hasn't yet exposed the functionality.

Comment: Now signatures are already "centralized" so you can use the same signature in client and OWA versions, but Graph does not support it. An alternative is using EWS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getuserconfiguration-operation